# How do I choose a regular expression match at an arbitrary index?

Tags: regex

I have a string that looks like:

> ABC-DEF01-GHI54677-JKL!9988-MNOP

Between each `-` can be virtually any character repeated any number of times.

I'm using this regular expression:

```
[^-]*
```

How do I make it 'match' the match at the 2nd index (e.g. DEF01)? Or the 3rd (GHI54677) or 4th (JKL!9988)?

The engine I'm using doesn't let me specify a match index or additional code - it has to all be done within the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second set of parens will capture "DEF", "GHI", and "JKL", respectively...

```
([^-]+-){1}([^-]+)
([^-]+-){2}([^-]+)
([^-]+-){3}([^-]+)
```

If this is perl, make the first set of parens non-capturing, i.e.:

```
# perl -de 0
$_="ABC-DEF-GHI-JKL-MNO"
p /(?:[^-]+-){1}([^-]+)/
  DEF
p /(?:[^-]+-){2}([^-]+)/
  GHI
p /(?:[^-]+-){3}([^-]+)/
  JKL

$_="ABC-DEF01-GHI54677-JKL!9988-MNOP"
p /(?:[^-]+-){1}([^-]+)/
  DEF01
p /(?:[^-]+-){2}([^-]+)/
  GHI54677
p /(?:[^-]+-){3}([^-]+)/
  JKL!9988
```

Explanation:

```
(?:  = non-capturing parens
[^-] = a non-dash character
+    = one or more
-    = a dash
)    = close paren
{3}  = repeat 3 times
```

This part "gobbles up" 1, 2, 3, or any number you like, of the blocks, leaving the next set to take the one you're looking for.

In lieu of `+`, you can also use `{1,}` meaning 1-to-any-number.

If your blocks can be zero size, so:

ABC--GHI-JKL

And you want to find the second, which is "" (empty string), then use `*` instead of `+`. Or you can use `{0,}`, meaning 0-to-any-number.

Comment: This answered my question but then I realised I'd written it incorrectly. My apologies, it's now been clarified.

Comment: no problem, just change `{3}` to `+` or `{1,}` if you mean 1-or-more-non-dash-things, or `*` or `{0,}` if you mean zero-or-more

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what language/regular expression engine you're using, but some (most?) let you keep applying a match over and over to the same string iteratively. For example, pcrecpp lets you do:

```
pcrecpp::StringPiece piece("ABC-DEF-GHI-JKL-MNO");
pcrecpp::RE re("([^-]+)-?");
unsigned int index = 3; // e.g., for GHI

std::string group;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < index; i++)
    re.Consume(&piece, &group);

// group now contains "GHI". Calling Consume again would give it JKL
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I can't use any additional code - it all has to be done within the expression. I've now clarified the question.

Answer (score 0):

Different answer based on your revision: Do you just want this?

```
(?:[^-]+-){index-1}([^-]+)
```

The non-capturing group matches `index-1` of the subblocks, so for `index=3` it matches `ABC-DEF01-`, and then the capturing group matches `GHI54677`